# SQL Server Except operator - how to identify culprit columns

Tags: sql-server, comparison, except

Just to give background, we have created new SSIS packages to get feeds into SQL Server tables.
To make sure new SSIS packages put data in same manner in which how current live process does, we have written comparison script to compare Live and Test tables which will be executed parallel for a month.

So have i have used EXCEPT command to get the differences and it returns data too which has differences.

Now problem is that, i have around 50 columns and i need to check data of each column and compare with other tables to find out the culprit.

In some cases, i am getting around 40000 rows as a difference and identifying correct columns is too cumbersome.

In most of the cases, it was because of NULL value in Live and blank value in Test. I have done following to identify columns

- Limit Number of columns
- Look at value for few columns and then change SQL statement to include ISNULL function & so on

This is time consuming.

Is there any good way to get the columns names because of which we are getting difference in rows.

It would be good if i can get better way to handle this.

Comment: It would be great, if somebody can give me pointers to look at :)

Comment: For now, i need to comments set of columns to identify the column which has different values in these tables. so in many cases, we have around 70 columns and it is cumbersome to identify